# Should this comma be placed here?

Tags: commas

Quick question:

In this sentence, should there be a comma? I've seen it both ways and both sound correct to me, but an English book I recently looked at (Erica Meltzer) said that the sentence was more proper without the comma.

> This period of prosperity from 1950 to 1973 brought upon the world a plethora of technological advances, which revolutionized society and allowed for significant scientific development.

Comment: Where (and why) has this sentence appeared in two variations?  What reasons do you have to doubt Erica Meltzer? Has anyone considered whether "from 1950 to 1973" should be set off by commas?

Comment: I believe that it is accepted that the commas around the date are optional, but do not detract from any meaning in either case. Erica Meltzer writes an ACT English preparatory book, which is purely American grammar in one test-oriented format. I am writing this sentence in an essay and I would like to know if one version is more proper than another, or if one version is British vs. American etc.

Comment: While my British friends insist that I can't spell, I believe that for the most part we are equally punctilious about punctuation.  If your question is really about preferred practices on either side of the Herring Pond, then you might consider rewriting it to reflect your main interest and purpose.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if there even is a difference in spelling between the countries across the herring pond...;)

Comment: I suppose it's the 'can _which_ refer to a whole clause' question again. _John broke the vase which really annoyed his mother_ vs _John broke the vase, which really annoyed his mother_. So (no comma) _This period of prosperity from 1950 to 1973 brought upon the world a plethora of technological advances, which advances revolutionized society and allowed for significant scientific development._ vs _This period of prosperity from 1950 to 1973 brought upon the world a plethora of technological advances, which development revolutionized society and allowed for significant advances in science._